# Jest - react-automata - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'machine.states')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, xstate

I'm currently working on testing my react component where I use react-automata. When I run the test it keeps breaking. The goal is to test my Lights component. I'm using the test function from react-automata called "testStateMachine" because I use a statemachine to run the steps of light switching on a button click.

Here is my code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/statemachine-test-sj3w7

This is the test that fails, with error "Cannot read property 'states' of undefined".

```js
import {testStateMachine} from 'react-automata';
import {Lights, lightMachine } from '../Components/Lights';

test('lights with imported components',()=>{
  testStateMachine({ lightMachine}, Lights);
});
```

Best regards
Kristine

Comment: Could you give more details on 'keeps breaking'? I can see `Transition: TIMER NextState: undefined` in the console, which looks dubious. Perhaps you can explain what you expect vs what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working test by changing the spec Lights.test.js from this:

```js
import {testStateMachine} from 'react-automata';
import {Lights, lightMachine } from '../Components/Lights';

test('lights with imported components',()=>{
  testStateMachine({ lightMachine}, Lights);
});
```

to this:

```js
import { testStateMachine, withStateMachine } from 'react-automata';
import { Lights } from '../Components/Lights';
import { lightMachine } from "../Xstate/Lightmachine";

test('lights with imported components', () => {

  const fixtures = {
    initialData: {
      states: {
        'greenText': 'green light',
        'yellowText':'yellow light',
        'redText':'red light'
      }
    }
  }

  const StateMachine = withStateMachine(lightMachine)(Lights)

  testStateMachine(StateMachine, { fixtures });
});
```

From the example spec [react-automata/test/testStateMachine.spec.js](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/react-automata/blob/master/test/testStateMachine.spec.js) you need to build the `StateMachine` first.

Then, since `App` supplies props to `Lights`, use fixtures.initialData to do the same in the test.

The test did not work in CodeSandbox, likely because I did not fork it - but it worked ok on my local machine.

**Further note**

The library seems to be fussy about the version of Jest. I had to down-grade from 24.9.0 you have in the sandbox to 24.7.1. Not sure why.

Comment: This helped alot, thank you so much. 

I have run into another problem. I have one component who has imported a custom react scrollbar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbars-custom). Whenever I run the test, the snapshot from the specific component gives the error

** scroller element was not created. Possibly you haven't provided HTMLDivElement to renderer's `elementRef` function.
`const StateMachine = withStateMachine(wizardSelvbetjeningMachine)(WizardSelvbetjening); 
 testStateMachine(StateMachine, { fixtures });  `**